# Swift test if a Type is compatible to another

Tags: swift

Imagine the following situation:

```
class Car {
}

class Mercedes: Car {
}

let aCarType: Any.Type = Mercedes.self
```

How would I test whether the type represented in `aCarType` **inherits** from `Car`?

```
aCarType is Car.Type
```

returns always false, of course.

Objective-C dynamic is not possible in my situation! **`aCarType` is populated in code over which I have no control.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift way of checking whether a class is equal to or a subclass of another class **is** using the `is` operator together with the `Type` property. Here's an example:

```
let c: Any.Type = UIButton.self        
print(c is UIButton.Type) // true
print(c is UIView.Type) // true
print(c is UILabel.Type) // false
```

As a result, the statement `aCarType is Car.Type` in your question should **always** evaluate to `true`. I verified that this is indeed the case in the latest releases of Xcode 6 (Swift 1.2) and Xcode 7 (Swift 2).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
if let carType = type as? Car.Type {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a type is of a specific class or subclass just with the `is` operator, this is the equivalent of `isKindOfClass` in Objective-C

```
class Car {}

class Mercedes: Car {}

let SLK = Mercedes()

SLK is Car // --> true
SLK is Mercedes // --> true
```

However if you want to check for a specific class but not for its superclass use `dynamicType`, this the equivalent of `isMemberOfClass` in Objective-C

```
SLK.dynamicType == Car.self // --> false
SLK.dynamicType == Mercedes.self // --> true
```

Comment: You are also working on instances, I need to check if two types represented by their *meta types* are compatible. I don’t not have instances of these types.

Comment: under what circumstances a type is checked without having an instance (and for what purpose)?